# Direct2D - using lighting effects in direct2d

Tags: lighting, direct2d

I got the direct2d lighting sample from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct2D-lighting-effects-e0801da3 URL. The sample looks very impressive, but what I don't understand is that after the lighting effects, pixel in the bitmap are always replaced by color of the light source, unlike direct3d, where each pixel color depends on the light and the object that reflects it. So my question is how can we use the lighting effect in direct2d to create lighting effect like we do in direct3d. so that I can create some amazing 2d effects like this..

http://svg-wow.org/blog/2009/10/04/chiseled/

Answer (score 0):

The lighting effect derives height maps from color information, while d3d typically uses vertices to define the dimensions of objects.  They are completely different systems.  The d2d effect is just a cheap and limited 3d height map which, while powerful, is much more limited than the d3d geometry system

Chiseled uses svg filters which are implemented in the latest IE11 using d2d effects.  For every svg filter there is a corresponding d2d effect that does the same thing.  Analyze the chiseled sample and you will be able to replicate it using d2d effects.